# A small operating system with a JVM and an X system?

Tags: java, swing, operating-system, executable-jar

I have a need for a very small, lightweight operating system (preferably even open source) that includes a fully featured JVM and X system for displaying my beautiful JFrames, and can auto execute the JAR file that I have it set up for. Anything good for me that's already built? Or will I have to build something like this myself off an existing Linux system?

Comment: How small? I believ there are plenty of linux distros that will fit in a 2GB pen drive.

Comment: No I think there are already Linux distros out there you can use. Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867571/small-linux-distro-for-demo-systems-that-still-runs-java.

Answer (score 1):

How about DSL - http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/
Only 50MB, has X(and Java also I believe) - not very beautiful though.
Or puppylinux - http://puppylinux.org - it is 100MB but much better looking